# Java : set property of nth object using nth value in list

Tags: java

I have two lists :

```
List1<MyObject> list1 = {myObject1, myObject2, myObject3};
List1<String> list2 = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I would like to know how I can achieve :

```
myObject1.setString("a")
myObject2.setString("b")
myObject3.setString("c")
```

using Java Stream ?
Please tell me if there is duplicated topic, but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .forEach((i) -> list1.get(i).setString(list2.get(i)));
```

should work.